# Playing video dumps .wav files into root directory until hard drive is full

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, video, codec

After playing a (Xvid) video on my laptop my hard drive space is zero.  Turns out loads of files like AC3_xxxxxx.wav are dumped to my C:\ root directory (where xxxxx are some seemingly random numbers).  The files vary in size from a few kB to hundreds of MBs, and also vary in quantity from, say, 4 to a couple dozen (though I suspect this is only because my drive runs out of space to create more).

I can't find any reference to this problem on the web.  Any ideas what this could be, or steps I can take to investigate the cause, would be much appreciated.

Comment: What software are you using to play the videos?

Comment: Media Player Classic.  VLC doesn't seem to have the same problem, so it's probably more a codec issue than player issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have activated, without knowing, a feature to extract AC3 audio from DVD playing. Check settings/preferences for mp4, dvd playback, extraction,codecs configuration (or global configuration of a codec pack if you install those things) in your player.

Imho is very possible that is just that, it is actually being told to extract audio tracks.